# Alternatives to using for-loops in image processing in python?

Tags: python, image, loops, image-processing

I'm new to image processing. It happens time and time again that I have to do an operation (like matrix multiplication) on all pixels of an image. Since I'm not a professional programmer, I always do this by writing two inner loops to loop through each pixel of the image and it usually takes a long time to run. I have been told that it's usually possible to use vectors instead of for-loops for doing this and using for-loops is inefficient. I'm also 100% sure that for-loops aren't the best way to do this because libraries like OpenCV can do the same thing in less than 5 seconds while my code takes a significantly longer time.

So, my question is: what are the alternatives to using for-loops when I need to apply matrix transformations to every pixels of an image? (consider homography transformations, for example)

Comment: Work through one or two numpy tutorials. The keyword is vectorization.

Comment: _I always do this by writing two inner loops_ What two things are you looping over?  Why aren't you (conceptually) just doing `for pixel in image`?

Comment: Numpy and many other libraries provide functions that do the same thing on every element in an array (pixel in an image). Use those functions. Write your logic in terms of those functions.

Comment: @stressedout there are other reasons for downvoting a question than the question being unclear. Your question is very clear, yet still very off-topic.

Comment: @timgeb  I agree that there could be other reasons for downvoting. I have been an active user on MSE from time to time. Generally speaking, if a question is off-topic, we write a comment under it and explain how it could be improved. We don't just downvote without explaining what's wrong with it.

Comment: @stressedout I guess MSE has less bad questions per second than SO. People here expect you to have read the "Asking" section of the [help] and will not always give an explanation for their downvote.

Comment: @stressedout I believe you're getting downvotes because you're asking a question that can have multiple (but perhaps inefficient) solutions. Rather than asking a specific algorithm, you're asking about a general idea. I always give an example on here: It's like asking how a computer works rather than asking how a _particular part_ in a computer works.

Comment: For loops are not inherently inefficient.  If your loops are written correctly so that each pixel is only processed once, then your problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: @timgeb  Believe me. We get hundreds of low quality questions there everyday. We always explain why a question is not suitable for the website or how the OP can improve their post.

Comment: @stressedout yeah, that's about a difference of a factor of ten.

Comment: @KingDuken Thanks. But you also have to agree that not everyone is a programmer. I believe the downvoting system on SE is there to improve the quality of posts, not just to make people think they don't belong here.

Comment: @JohnGordon  Well, let's say I want to do an affine transformation on a photo. I have done it by for-loops and by using libraries. And each pixel is only processed once. There's a significance difference in elapsed times between our algorithms.

Comment: I think the downvoting system can let the OP know that they're not asking the question properly because it doesn't follow the objectives of the website. You can redeem your lost points by deleting your question (unless someone answers the question). Digressing... But there a few (but extremely slow in executing) ways I can think about doing this... such as branching... and lists... and defining functions... or using `reduce`!  I think better question here to ask whether or not there are alternatives to using loops.

Comment: @KingDuken  Yes, thanks for the help. I can't care less about the reputation points lost here. I still think only losers would downvote a post without explaining why. I can't read people's minds. Being downvoted means that people didn't like my question. But it tells me nothing about how I should improve it. Anyway, I'm going to ask for alternatives to for-loops. Please feel free to write an answer. I'm not going to delete my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with your comment that people shouldn't downvote questions from people authentically looking for help. Anyway:

The simple answer is to try and use numpy. So for instance you may be filling an array like this:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros((100, 100), dtype=np.uint8)
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        x[i][j] = 10
```

But you could do this much more cleanly and quickly like this:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros((100, 100), dtype=np.uint8)
x += 10
```

Or:

```
import numpy as np
x = 10*np.ones((100, 100), dtype=np.uint8)
```

etc.

If you need to apply a common operation to all pixels, then a numpy broadcast operation is a quick and easy way to go. There are many common image processing operations available in numpy, scipy, and elsewhere (go look at OpenCV's python features, they're great) that let you use simple syntax like the above and that will run many orders of magnitude faster than 2 Python loops. It's also easy to apply operations to subsets of images using slicing

If you have some complicated operation that isn't easily offloaded to a numpy or scipy function, then I recommend taking a look at the Numba module. It lets you write functions using loops (as is your instinct) and then compile them, and then those loops execute very quickly. This can require a bit of planning and forethought, as you get the best speed when you combine multiple operations in the innermost loop but you also want to be working with primitives as much as possible and shouldn't just compile everything.

Comment: Thank you, Michael. This answer helped me. (+1). The thing is that I'm a pure math student taking a course in 3D Reconstruction from the computer engineering department. We have to write every algorithm like finding homographies, interests points, etc. from scratch on our own and we are not allowed to use OpenCV or similar libraries for that. I have written all the codes using for-loops, but then somebody told me there were more efficient ways to do the calculations. Anyway, could you please explain your last paragraph? So, after I have compiled a part of my code, how can I load it in python?

Comment: You define the function normally, and you decorate it with @jit (or @jit with some options). In other words you're just adding 1 line right before the function declaration. From there you just call the function normally, as though it were a normal Python function. Numba will auto-compile the function for you using a just-in-time (JIT) compiler.

The key to squeezing performance out of Numba functions is to be very explicit with the @jit options; passing the `nopython=True` flag and explicitly defining the variable types going in and out of the function can result in huge performance boosts

Comment: But note that Numba can make debugging a pain, and you need to be careful to be using primitive types as much as possible (floats, ints, etc). I recommend trying to use Numpy as much as possible first, then if you really can't escape from nested for loops then try moving them to a function and test to make sure you have the desired behavior, then compile it with Numba's @jit decorator (with nopython=True and the function signature explicitly declared, ideally; there are tutorials out there that can show this in more detail)

Comment: Thanks. I looked up 'numba' and I found many interesting stuff about it. It's an amazing functionality in python really. Thank you for introducing it. :)